# What's the best way to evangelize Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, site-promotion

What would be the best thing that a stack overflow evangelist could do? What would be the best way to promote the site over other sites like expetsexchange and other question sights? What opportunities would there be for selling stackoverflow to companies to use for their own products?

Comment: Start with beatitudes: "Blessed are the askers, for their questions shall be answered."

Answer (score 13):

stackoverflow.com - the website - already has well 9 million monthly unique visitors, and is overflowing. That particular website needs no evangelism.

[The Stack Exchange network](http://stackexchange.com), a product of Stack Overflow, the company, could use someone to help all the 25-odd young communities grow and thrive. In the first three months growth has been tremendous (zero to 550,000 unique monthly visitors) but there are a lot of important communities we'd love to see created, and that needs a lot more "buzz" out there in the world.

As a company, it is NOT our goal to sell Stack Overflow to companies. We're building something for the PUBLIC internet. Our mission is to "make the internet a better place to get expert answers."

Comment: Do you have any stats on how much overlap there is between the Stack Overflow traffic and the 550k visitors/month Stack Exchange traffic?

Comment: @Jon, my guess would be 100%, give or take ~0%.

Comment: If certification is ever required to work as a programmer, I hope guessing is considered an ethical violation.

Answer (score 3):

I think these could be some good ways to reach a wider audience for general SE sites, not just SO

1. #### Reach for the online celebrities of each
   community.

   Being an online product, its first market should obviously be people who are online, specifically people who are online and involve in a community in some way (even if it is pasively, like reading a blog), if we get the celebrities -people trusted in those communities -  to talk about the sites in their blogs and tweets, then a lot of their viewers would certainly come here.

   Find who ever the Scott Hanselman, Jeff Atwood, Joel Spolsy, Rob Conery, Scott Gu, etc are for the online cooking, math, photograpy, etc comunities and invite them over to do podcasts, shows, or some kind of activity. Show them the product, have them review it,  and basically convince them with facts of why the SE network is so good (they also get to expose their own blogs to a larger comunity), so they themselves will promote it.
2. #### Traffic referee program.

   A more business centric approach would be to offer some sort of traffic referee program. Why not give an economic for people who own domains from which a considerable amount of traffic comes? (just dont let google become an affiliate or you are gonna be broke) I mean, most traffic comes from google, that be a way to get other sources.
3. #### Question flair

   More social elements have been added to the SE pages, such as the twitter  and facebook buttons, what about a button to make some sort of question flair to put in others people pages (could help with the trafic referee program too). It could be individual for a question, to show your top questions/answers.
4. #### Questions widget - Automatic Relevant FAQ

   Related to the previous point, there could be a hot questions widget/plugin (similar to the one on every SE page) that people could put in their blogs. Say I write a blog post about EF code first and sql compact edition (or fried salmon tacos), I could feed those tags to the plugin and then the plugin would find relevant questions, this way OTHER peoples blog will have relevant FAQs for each blog they publish, (maybe with an option to always include an specific question) and thus *making a bigger part of the internet a better place!*
5. #### All out online ad campaign

   The expensive option, brainstorm and find great, really really GREAT questions in the SE sites and have ads for them in popular pages such as Facebook. There are usually some very good questions in the left bar of the SE pages that lead to  other SE pages, it could be something similar but to attract external visitors.

Comment: I think you should post 3 and 4 as feature suggestions.

Comment: @Benjol I've made proper request for them http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67782/question-flair-widget and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67785/question-widget-automatic-relevant-faq-generator