# Question Flair/Widget

Tags: feature-request, questions, flair

As more social features are being added to StackExchange, how about a flair for questions? This would be like the flair used in the chat, but embeddable in other websites:

[image: chat question flair]

There could also be an option to show the top questions/answers for a user. This comes from [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67710/whats-the-best-way-to-evangelize-stack-overflow/67713#67713).

Comment: @Simon thanks for the great edit :p I edited the picture though... couldnt resist the urge to have a question include flair of itself :P

Answer (score 5):

There's an app called [StackTack](https://stackapps.com/questions/518/stacktack-a-javascript-widget-you-can-stick-anywhere) that does essentially this:

[image: Example of StackTack on this question]

Comment: ha definite +1 for also using a screenshot of this question in this question :)

Comment: I think thats a pretty cool app, but I was thinking of something that could be used inline

Comment: @bangoker Used inline where? You can use it inline on any site that lets you include scripts

Comment: I meant inline content-wise, so like you could put it in the middle of a paragraph, where it wouldn't interrupt the flow of something you were writing about, like the one in the chat