# Question Widget / Automatic relevant FAQ generator

Tags: feature-request

Again from my suggestions here [What's the best way to evangelize Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67710/whats-the-best-way-to-evangelize-stack-overflow/67713#67713)

I think it would be nice to have a widget/plugin (similar to the hot questions one on the top left of every SE, but not collapsed) that people could put in their blogs, and on each post feed them with tags(or it could automatically search for popular tags that match the blog content) and then the plugin would find relevant questions on the SE pages. This way OTHER people's blog will have relevant FAQs for each post they publish, (maybe with an option to always include a specific question) and thus making a bigger part of the internet a better place!

Example:
Say I write a blog post about EF code first and sql compact edition (or about the nutrition value of onion), my post will have tags "EF", "Code first", "SQLCE" (or "Food", "Onion"), the plugin then gets populated with related questions about those themes, maybe things like this:

[Looking for a complete example of Entity Framework 4 Code First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148657/looking-for-a-complete-example-of-entity-framework-4-code-first)
[Entities Framework 4 Code First: Inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910100/entities-framework-4-code-first-inheritance)
[Code-First or Database-First, how to choose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919880/code-first-or-database-first-how-to-choose)

or in case of the onions

[How can I chop onions without crying?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/567/how-can-i-chop-onions-without-crying)
https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/8119/what-can-i-do-with-a-bunch-of-onions
[How to caramelise onions?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/2391/how-to-caramelise-onions)

I thinks this kind of widgets are A LOT more useful in a blog than say a Tag Cloud and actually make the whole internet a better place (or at least the blogs that use it)